Is there something like a compact surface classificator?
I'm currently studying compact surfaces and there are some exercises as the following: find a simple scheme equivalent to $abc, da^{-1}b,cef,e^{-1}f^{-1}d$ and classify the surface.
After computations I found that one equivalent shceme is $bdbf^{-1}d^{-1}f$, and that the surface it represents is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^2_3$. However I don't know if this is correct. Is there a website or something similar where I could enter the scheme and get the surface?
